# Gradle Transitive Dependency issue local ivy

Tags: java, gradle, ant, ivy

I am converting a ivy + ant project to gradle and I made the build.gradle file which refers to a projectA(downloads its jar) but the dependencies listed in projectA are not downloaded in my project

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'


repositories {

     ivy  {
        url 'http://ivyrepodomain:8080/repo'
        layout 'pattern', {
              artifact 'snapshot/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
              artifact '3rd-party/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
              artifact 'b2bdev/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
              ivy '3rd-party/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml'
              ivy 'snapshot/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml'
        }
    }

}
targetCompatibility = sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

dependencies {


    testCompile('mygroup:projectA:17.20.SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.wicket'
        exclude group: 'org.wicketstuff'
    }
    testCompile('org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.1.Final') {
        transitive = false
    }
    testCompile('org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.1.2.Final') {
        transitive = false
    }
    testCompile('org.javassist:javassist:3.16.1-GA') {
        transitive = false
    }
    compileOnly('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    compileOnly('dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    testCompile('mygroup:projectA:17.20.SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.wicket'
        exclude group: 'org.wicketstuff'
    }
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.187') {
        transitive = false
    }
    testCompile('org.apache.derby:derby:10.11.1.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    testCompile('org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.4') {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

The project A has some dependencies as in this ivy-17.20.SNAPSHOT.xml(hosted on the ivy repo) file below

```
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info organisation="mygroup" module="projectA" revision="17.20.SNAPSHOT" status="integration" publication="434334345"></info>
<configurations>
<conf name="test" visibility="public" description="Dependencies needed only for testing"/>
<conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="Dependencies required for compile time that are not provided by a container"/>
<conf name="runtime" extends="compile" visibility="public" description="Dependencies not needed for compile time but are needed for runtime"/>
<conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="Dependencies provided by a container"/>
<conf name="ear" visibility="public" description="Dependencies managed by ear level classloader"/>
<conf name="war" visibility="public" description="Dependencies managed by war level classloader"/>
<conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
<conf name="optional" visibility="public"/>
<conf name="sources" visibility="public"/>
</configurations>
<publications>
<artifact name="projectA"/>
<artifact name="projectA-sources" type="src" ext="jar" conf="sources"/>
</publications>
<dependencies>

<!--  Spring and related dependencies  -->
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-expression" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-tx" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context-support" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-oxm" rev="4.1.6.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.data" name="spring-data-neo4j" rev="2.1.0.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.data" name="spring-data-neo4j-tx" rev="2.1.0.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="2.1.8.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-infrastructure" rev="2.1.8.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-core" rev="3.2.4.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-web" rev="3.2.4.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-config" rev="3.2.4.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-ldap" rev="3.2.4.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.ldap" name="spring-ldap" rev="1.3.0.RELEASE" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.velocity" name="velocity" rev="1.7" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="aopalliance" name="aopalliance" rev="1.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.microsoft.sqlserver" name="sqljdbc" rev="4.0.2206.100" transitive="false" conf="provided->default"/>
<dependency org="com.ibm.db2" name="db2jcc" rev="3.62.56" conf="provided->default"/>
<dependency org="com.ibm.db2" name="db2jcc_license" rev="1.0" conf="provided->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-beanutils" name="commons-beanutils" rev="1.8.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-dbcp" name="commons-dbcp" rev="1.2.2" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-pool" name="commons-pool" rev="1.5.2" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.2" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-io" name="commons-io" rev="1.4" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-httpclient" name="commons-httpclient" rev="3.1" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.6" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="16.0.1" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-core" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-annotation" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-servlet" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-web" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-spring" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.yammer.metrics" name="metrics-logback" rev="2.2.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.wicket" name="wicket-core" rev="1.5.13" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.wicket" name="wicket-ioc" rev="1.5.13" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.wicket" name="wicket-spring" rev="1.5.13" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.wicket" name="wicket-util" rev="1.5.13" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.wicket" name="wicket-request" rev="1.5.13" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="4.1.2.Final" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate.javax.persistence" name="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" rev="1.0.1.Final" transitive="false" conf="provided->default"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.1.0.Final" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.jasypt" name="jasypt" rev="1.9.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.jasypt" name="jasypt-hibernate4" rev="1.9.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="net.sf.ehcache" name="ehcache-core" rev="2.5.1" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-core" rev="1.0.9" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.9" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.2" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.7.2" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="log4j-over-slf4j" rev="1.7.2" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="cglib" name="cglib-nodep" rev="2.1_3" transitive="false" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default"/>
<dependency org="com.rsa" name="axm-runtime-api" rev="6.1" conf="compile->default; war->default; ear->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="com.rsa" name="jsafeJCE" rev="3.5.2" conf="runtime->default; war->default; ear->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" rev="3.0.1" conf="provided->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="javax.transaction" name="jta" rev="1.1" conf="provided->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.unitils" name="unitils-core" rev="3.4.2" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.unitils" name="unitils-database" rev="3.4.2" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.unitils" name="unitils-dbunit" rev="3.4.2" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.unitils" name="unitils-orm" rev="3.4.2" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.unitils" name="unitils-spring" rev="3.4.2" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.dbunit" name="dbunit" rev="2.4.8" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="1.9.0" conf="compile->default;test->default" transitive="false"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Kindly help in resolving this
Thanks

Comment: Does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17329712/4121573 Also what do you mean by "not resolved" any error stacktrace? What is gradle's output?

Comment: @asettouf it is not downloading the jars in ProjectA's ivy.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Single ivy module multi project gradle build** is given in this tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/BorePlusPlus/4145778

### Complete Example

There is a complete example with demonstration which is publishing with a multi-project build: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html#publishing_ivy:example

Hope this will clarify your ivy and gradle combination for multi project.

---

You also need to add

```
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'
```

thats one you not added in your `build.gradle` file also.

For more, you can go through this tutorial: [Getting Started With Gradle: Creating a Multi-Project Build](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-multi-project-build/)

---

### UPDATE#1:

I have create a project in github https://github.com/rizvi/java-multi-project

Clone the project and run the following 2 command

1. gradle clean
2. gradle jar

### Console

```
mac@My-PC:~/Desktop/gradleproject/java-multi-project$ gradle jar
:project2:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:project2:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:project2:classes UP-TO-DATE
:project2:copyToLib
:project2:jar
:project1:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:project1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:project1:classes UP-TO-DATE
:project1:copyToLib
:project1:jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 20.337 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

This will create 2 project. They are

i) project1

ii) project2

> In project1/build/lib folder you will get
>   `commons-collections-3.2.2.jar`, `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar`,
>   `junit-4.12.jar` and `project2-1.0.jar`.
>
> In project2/build/lib folder you will get
>   `commons-collections-3.2.2.jar` only

Here project1 is dependent on project2. So project1 contains project2's jar file and dependent jar files.

Hope it will fulfill your demand. :)

---

### UPDATE#2:

There is a plugin named by gradle-ivyxml-plugin. but it has various types of obstacles. They are given below.

1. Purposefully does not do anything with any `ivysettings.xml` file.
2. Purposefully ignores publishing-related `ivy.xml` elements and
   attributes.

### UNSUPPORTED ivy.xml features

Most ivy.xml elements and attributes are supported. Here we document those which are not.

The following ivy.xml elements and attributes are ignored. I did my best to detect and either, support, throw or warn, but the public Ivy API just does not allow for access to these settings.

```
<conflicts> (and all attrs and sub-elements)
<dependencies><dependency><conf>  (For conf-mapping)
<dependencies><dependency><artifact conf="...">  attr.
<dependencies><dependency><*><conf>
```

The following elements and attribute are purposefully prohibited. We don't support them, it would be misleading to silently ignore then, and we can detect their usage.

```
<dependencies><dependency><exclude artifact="..." type="..."
    ext="..." matcher="..." cont="..."
    (i.e. only 'org' and 'module' attrs are supported).
<dependencies><override>
<dependencies><dependency branch="..." force="..."  attrs.
 (Branch and force have no support in Gradle).
```

### Resource Link:

https://github.com/unsaved/gradle-ivyxml-plugin/tree/master/doc

### Customized minimum solution is available here:

1. http://technicallypossible.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-ivyxml-with-gradle.html

Comment: The projectA's source is not available I just need my project to download ProjectA's jar and its dependencies. How will this help me kindly explain

Comment: @CognitiveDesire I have updated my answer and created a sample project on github. Please check and let me know.

Comment: according to your gradle file you declared dependencies of Project2 there, It means I have to declare tons of ProjectA dependencies in my build.gradle file can't it refer the ivy.xml of ProjectA to download the jars

Comment: @CognitiveDesire If you want to use ivy.xml, then there is not much better solution to do that. It is technically possible but there is some formats. For more, you can go through this tutorial: http://technicallypossible.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-ivyxml-with-gradle.html.

Comment: I guess I was taking this gradle thing entirely wrong, I thought if a project has some dependencies their jars get downloaded and the dependencies of those jars also get downloaded if transitive is set to true. I never knew we have to define dependencies of 1st level jars in our build.gradle file